# Android app switcher change the image of last screen

Tags: android

When we minimize the android application, then app goes in task switcher and it goes to pause condition. When we click the task switcher the application image(not the icon of the app) is the last screen we have left. I want to change that image , please provide a solution for it

Comment: you want to change the colour in of app in task switcher ?

Comment: no i want to change the screenshot which shows of the last screen in task switcher. I want their a customised image.

Answer (score 0):

Although this method isn't guaranteed to work always, and given that there is no official ways(that I know of) for achieving what I think your question is, here is what came to my mind:

Since mostly the Screenshot of your app in 'Recent tasks' pane is the screen Android sees last, you could try changing your last layout to the image you want just as onPause() is called. This COULD work, although I cant make any promises!

Answer (score 0):

The "Launcher" or "Homescreen" application differs on each device by each manufacturer.

If all you need is a "image" to replace that, on your `onPause()` function, load that image over your `Layout` or your highest `View`, then in the `onResume()`, remove that image.

Something such as:

```
onCreate(){
   aHiderView = // Load your image, or whatever you want;
}

onPause(){
   aHiderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

onResume(){
   aHiderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are using/used? I use this concept myself and it works so far on all but some motorola devices. (those devices replace your image with a "thumbnail" of the icon, so nothing can be done there), on the rest, specially over API 19 (KitKat) everything works as expected. Edit your question, post the device / OS version, as well as the expected behavior, and the watched behavior..... Editted: Please note, I have misplaced the onPause/onResume functions. Check again now.... Show on pause, hide on resume